# How to scale the top of a mesh w/o distorting the structure

Tags: mesh, modifiers, scale, distort

How can I make the top I need the top of my build narrower than the bottom?  On the right, you can see the effect I am trying to achieve.  I needed to add windows to the original downloaded build so I just started over with a grid mesh so I could get everything even. Then mirrored and merged to get the four sides.  I tried morphing as suggested in a youtube video from a similar question on this site., but it flattened everything out.  It's not a cylinder so I can't simply circle select and scale.  I am sure there is some simple modifier for this, but I can't seem to frame the question in the proper format to search for it.

[image]

Comment: It's a bit free-hand, but have you tried the lattice modifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do that is to use a *'simple deform modifier'* and its *'taper'* function.

[image]

Comment: Okay, this solution is better. And procedural. :)

Answer (score 1):

One way would be *Proportional Scaling*.

1. Select the top part and scale it, Keep Z=1 (to keep the height)
2. Enable proportional editing and set it to *Linear*
3. Use the slider to adjust the faloff distance

[image]

[image]

Comment: I knew it would be something simple!  Worked great - thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked for you :). Make me happy by upvoting the answer as well :). Cheers.

Comment: To be honest with you I thought that's what I did when I check marked it - still new to this.  Problem is, I discovered some parts of it came apart and didn't scale, so I started over again.  Now it doesn't work at all and I'm perplexed...then wouldn't you know, as soon as I try to record what it was doing, it worked fine!  Bangs head on desk....

Comment: No worries, Blender sometimes acts up :). If you get stuck somewhere feel free to post a new question. Good luck.